# Is there a Scala shortcut for "lst filter isinstanceof map asinstanceof"?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a List[T] where E extends T. I want to get all E's in the list.
I have to do something like:

```
    val l = list filter {_.isInstanceof[E]} map {_.asInstanceOf[E]}
```

Any better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: This was one of the first idioms, or anti-idioms, I encountered when I first looked at Scala code.  I wonder why it doesn't receive more attention in the FAQ. It's prolly a dupe on SO, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [`collect`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.4/src/library/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.scala#L190-L210):

```
scala> trait Quux
defined trait Quux

scala> case class Bar() extends Quux
defined class Bar

scala> case class Baz() extends Quux
defined class Baz

scala> val l = List(Bar(), Baz())
l: List[Product with Serializable with Quux] = List(Bar(), Baz())

scala> l.collect { case bar:Bar => bar }
res1: List[Bar] = List(Bar())
```